# Select a number from two sets each that the sum of their multiplication equals to a specific sum

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random

I have two sets like A={0,1,2,...,i} and B={3,6,10,15}, a constant $s$, and a specified number $n$ which belongs to the natural numbers set. 
I want to find a/all combinations that satisfy a_1*b_1+a_2*b_2+\dots+a_n*b_n>=s

For example, if s=25, n=2 each of following answers is acceptable 1*10+1*15 , 2*10+1*6 , 0+2*15 or 4*3+2*6

If I didn't have the second set it would be easy because the problem reduces to producing random partitions with predetermined sum s as introduced in [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23728/generating-random-sequences-while-keeping-sum-fixed)

How should I efficiently implement this in python? any mathematical way to do it? 
It also reminds me of some kind of equation but I'm not sure what I should search for. 
I appreciate any hint.

Edit: It is important for me to have exactly "n" terms in my answer and there is chance for other alternatives. In my example, each of four answers should have a chance for generation. In other words, I have "n" place to fill them with my terms such that their sum equals to "s". Sorry not to clear it at first place.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by straight-forward recursion.

```
from functools import lru_cache

def find_combinations(numbers, threshold, nterms, maxcoeff, stringify=True):
    numbers = sorted(numbers, reverse=True)
    @lru_cache(None)
    def rec(k, s, n):
        if s > maxcoeff * numbers[k]:
            top = maxcoeff
            res = []
        else:
            top = (s-1) // numbers[k]
            res = [[top + 1]]
        if n > 1 and k < len(numbers)-1:
            for j in range(top, -1, -1):
                res.extend([[j, *subres] for subres in rec(
                    k+1, s-j*numbers[k], n-(j!=0))])
        return res
    if stringify:
        return [' + '.join(f'{c}\u2a2f{n}' for c, n in zip(sol, numbers) if c)
                for sol in rec(0, threshold, nterms)]
    else:
        return rec(0, threshold, nterms)

print(find_combinations({3, 6, 10, 15}, 25, 2, 2))
```

Prints:

```
['2⨯15', '1⨯15 + 1⨯10', '2⨯10 + 1⨯6']
```

**Update:** allowing `numbers` to occcur multiple times (these are lumped together, basically maxcoeff is multiplied with the number of occurrences of each number):

```
def find_combinations_with_replacement(numbers, threshold, nterms, maxcoeff,
                                       stringify=True):
    numbers = sorted(numbers, reverse=True)
    @lru_cache(None)
    def rec(k, s, n):
        if s > maxcoeff * numbers[k] * n:
            return []
        top = (s-1) // numbers[k]
        res = [[top + 1]]
        if n > 1 and k < len(numbers)-1:
            for j in range(top, -1, -1):
                res.extend([[j, *subres] for subres in rec(
                    k+1, s-j*numbers[k], n - (j-1) // maxcoeff - 1)])
        return res
    if stringify:
        return [' + '.join(f'{c}\u2a2f{n}' for c, n in zip(sol, numbers) if c)
                for sol in rec(0, threshold, nterms)]
    else:
        return rec(0, threshold, nterms)

print(find_combinations_with_replacement({3, 6, 10, 15}, 25, 4, 1))
```

Prints:

```
['2⨯15', '1⨯15 + 1⨯10', '1⨯15 + 2⨯6', '1⨯15 + 1⨯6 + 2⨯3', '3⨯10', '2⨯10 + 1⨯6', '2⨯10 + 2⨯3', '1⨯10 + 3⨯6', '1⨯10 + 2⨯6 + 1⨯3']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I call it with "find_combinations({3, 6, 10, 15}, 25, 4,1,True)" it always returns me ['1⨯15 + 1⨯10'] but  ['1⨯3+1⨯3+1⨯3+3⨯6'] and ['0⨯3+2⨯3+1⨯3+3⨯6']  is also a possible solution. I need that there is a chance(uniform distribution) to generate them too, not just one possible solution. I think "maxcoeff" prevents it.  How should I go for that? I added some more info to my question. thanks again

Comment: @roadstorm Ah, I assumed that the elements of `B` may occur only once. `maxcoeff` is the same as `i`. (Here I assumed that `A` is always of the form `0, 1, 2, 3, ..., i`).

Comment: Thanks but I still have problem with its output. When I set n=9 and s=25 I cannot get an answer like $['1⨯3+1⨯3+1⨯3+1⨯3+1⨯3+1⨯3+1⨯3+1⨯3+1⨯3']$. "maxcoeff" is a very handy variable to cap 'i'. How about making the sum to be exactly equal to s, can it help to reduce feasible space? Thank you

Comment: @roadstorm To make the output a bit shorter these are lumped together into one term `9x3`. One could expand that in a second step but it would accelerate the combinatorial explosion.

Comment: Maybe we should add some kind of randomness to solution selection to generate different answers each time I run the algorithm? Edit: I will take a look to understand your last comment. thanks